# update specific attribute value by setup upgrade

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade

I want to change the frontend_label value of an attribute_code 'xx' only by using upgradedata.php script!

```
$table = $setup->getTable('eav_attribute');
            $setup->getConnection()
                ->update($table, 
                ['frontend_label' => 'new version'],
                 ['attribute_code= ?' => 'xx']
                );
        }
```

I tried this in upgradedata.php but not working

Comment: check my answer I have updated the product and customer attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
 <?php
 namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;
    
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

    
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.3') < 0) {
            //update product attribute
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'attribute_code', 'frontend_label','new_version');

            //update customer attribute
            $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_code',
            'frontend_label',
            'new_version'
        );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I don't see how we can choose the specific attribute_code 'xx'

Answer (score 0):

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','frontend_input','text');
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_type','decimal');
```

- Frontend input should be text
- Backend type should be decimal

If wanting it to be a price, don't forget to add backend model: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price. And frontend_input should be price, backend_type should be decimal.

```
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType, 'as_low_as', 'frontend_input','price', null);
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_type','decimal');
$eavSetup->updateAttribute($entityType,'as_low_as','backend_model','Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price');
```

Comment: Please read my qustion , your answer doesn't match to what I'm looking for

Comment: You can try again with my method
https://pastebin.com/ka6yuThX